# How to cache block devices (for device mapper)?

Tags: cache, block-device, device-mapper

**problem / observed effect**

It seems that the page cache ignores block devices which are not opened. And worse: Reads from device mapper (DM) devices which use a cached device are not cached at all (unless opened).

I use this command (in repetition) for testing:

```
time dd if=/dev/sda11 of=/dev/null bs=50M count=1
```

If `sda11` is opened for reading (`exec 4</dev/sda11`), mounted or part of a device mapper device (`echo "0 1427456 linear /dev/sda11 0" | dmsetup create cache1`) then the cache works.

But if I create /dev/mapper/cache1 on top of sda11 neither the first read nor the second one comes from the cache (if it is not opened somehow).

**motivation**

The reason why I am doing this: I have an encrypted volume and booting my (KDE) system takes quite a while. I do some manual preparations before I open the encrypted volume thus I thought I might use this time for reading from the encrypted device (LVM) in order to speed up the KDE start. But for the mentioned caching problem this is of no use.

**question**

Is there any trick to read from the LV in a way that the later created DM crypto device reads from it through the (filled) cache?

Comment: Just a guess:try something as losetup for `/dev/mapper/mapperdevice` or anything to make it opend in background in initramfs script?